# How to use "await" in sails when creating a new record

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to use "await"

According to the sails documentation I act as follows:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create

```
create: function (req, res, next) {

var new_place = await Place.create({...}, function place_created(err, XX){

  if(err && err.invalidAttributes) {
    return res.json({'status':false, 'errors':err.Errors});
  } 
}).fetch();
if(new_place){
  console.log(new_place);
  res.json({'status':true,'result':new_place});
 }
},
```

But I get the following Error:

```
var new_place = await Place.create({...}, function place_created(err, XX){
                ^^^^^
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

what should I do to fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

This is because you are using `await` in a function that is not `async`

> Remember, **the await keyword is only valid inside async functions**. If you use it outside of an async function's body, you will get a SyntaxError.

**Source** [MDN async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

You need to make the function `async` for it to work. Making those changes in your code,

```
'use strict';

create: async function(req, res, next) {
        var new_place = await Place.create({ ... }, function place_created(err, XX) {
            if (err && err.invalidAttributes) {
                return res.json({ 'status': false, 'errors': err.Errors });
            }
        }).fetch();
        if (new_place) {
            console.log(new_place);
            res.json({ 'status': true, 'result': new_place });
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make your function async.

```
 async(function(){
   var new_place = await Place.create({...})
})();
```

And if you are using await you should not use callbacks. You should manage the response as explained [here](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/async-await-error-handling)

[Also you can check this guide of how to manage async in sail.js](http://www.piedcode.com/handling-async-functions-in-sails-js/)

Comment: thanks a lot ,It was a good tip,You also introduced good references