# Sails.JS's publish method doesn't work in a controller, but works in the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, sails.js, sails.io.js

Currently, I'm exploring web development to see what all the hype is about. Except for following a small 'create your first CRUD app in Node.JS' and some formal training in JavaScript, I have no experience.

I'm new to JavaScript, NodeJS, Sails.JS, and WebSockets.

My current problem is this:

The app I'm trying to develop receives POST calls with a JSON object. This is the input part of the application. These POST calls originate from any random host.

The output is a webpage that updates itself by listening on a Sails.JS powered WebSocket system called sails.io.js.

Basically, each POST from any host should result in an event on the WebSocket.

Since I'm not building a formal REST API, I have to define some parts myself in Sails.JS. I do have blueprints enabled.

First, in the controller that handles the POST call, I can call the code below so existing WebSockets can receive an event of a new ServiceHeartBeatSession being created. All the server side code mentioned here is located in the controller or executed in the console.

```
sails.sockets.addRoomMembersToRooms(ServiceHeartBeatSession._classRoom()
 , ServiceHeartBeatSession._room(session.id) );
```

Then, the invoke method is executed to send this event to all listening WebSockets.

```
ServiceHeartBeatSession.publish([ session.id ], { "verb": "created" });
```

However, the .publish method does not result in a event to an existing WebSocket.  Unless I execute it myself in the console. The WebSocket is registered like this:

```
io.socket.on('serviceheartbeatsession', function(resData) {
    alert('Something changed!!!!');
  });
```

I did some digging into the sourcecode and made some attempts at debugging this myself. Here's what I've found so far:

- Running the .publish call in the console produces the desired result.
- It appears that the .addRoomMembersToRooms is a requirement for the .publish to work in the console. So I'm assuming that .addRoomMembersToRooms works as intended.
- I tried the alternative below, but that doesn't work in the controller. However, it does work in the Node console.

  ```
  sails.sockets.broadcast([ ServiceHeartBeatSession._room(session.id) ], "serviceheartbeatsession", 'hi!');
  ```
- The following works as intended, but I prefer not to use that.

  ```
  sails.io.sockets.emit('serviceheartbeatsession', { verb: 'created' });
  ```
- The above attempt lacked a room selection, so I dug a little deeper. The calls below where the result of a .publish method. However, only after repeating this in the console, it worked.

  ```
  var emitter = sails.io.sockets;
  emitter.in('sails_model_serviceheartbeatsession_5b6b26748377829d34983d67:serviceheartbeatsession'); // for example
  emitter.emit('serviceheartbeatsession', { verb: "created" });
  ```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If anyone has any idea on how to get rid of the 'Run code snippet' buttons then I'm all ears.

Comment: If your not placing your code to run then the format your looking for is to slam the space key 4times then insert your code example.

Comment: Also checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594267/how-to-use-await-in-sails-when-creating-a-new-record) issue might help.

Comment: I tried to use await for both commands, no dice. Thanks.

Comment: Your attempt gave my an idea. I stuck a
     await new Promise(done => setTimeout(done, 2));

Between the addRoomMembersToRooms and the publish method, then it works. Should I file a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sails.sockets.addRoomMembersToRooms(ServiceHeartBeatSession._classRoom()
           , ServiceHeartBeatSession._room(session.id), () => {
    ServiceHeartBeatSession.publish([ session.id ], { "verb": "created" });
});
```

The documentation says there is a callback for it. Missed that, hehe.