# Can't connect to MySQL in Sails with PlanetHoster server

Tags: mysql, sails.js

After two weeks of trying to run my site, I'm asking for your help.

Has anyone hosted Sails.JS on PlanetHoster?

My queries don't work because the connection to the database doesn't seem established.

Here's an example of some very simple queries:

```
await User.findOne({ email: email });
```

Here's what's displayed in the browser error console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

I've tried to handle the errors but nothing is displayed...

```
try { await User.findOne({ email: email }); } catch(err) { // nothing }
```

So I've deduced that it was a problem with calling the database.
Unfortunately, I have no way to read the error logs ...

Yet, I've set the production.js file *(config/env/production.js)* and when I run *NODE_ENV = production node app.js*, it's still displayed in development. In fact, PlanetHoster doesn't require running the command `sails lift`, it just runs the platform already ...

I'm currently in a total blur as for where to go from here so if you have suggestions, I will take them with pleasure.

Thank you

Environment: Sails v1.0.2

Comment: Could you add more of your code? 
I see your using await but I am not sure if you have it in an async function.
Check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49594267/how-to-use-await-in-sails-when-creating-a-new-record) out for ideas.

Comment: Actually, it was an error from an undefined model. The module who links the database to the models had disappeared. (sails-hook-orm).

Comment: Try to use pm2 in your server - its the best tool. Then run `NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js` after connecting via ssh. And with `pm2 logs` you can easily read the logs. 
Try to check your connection to DB with other model than User.